# Two consecutive issues: carrierwave and polymorphic show nothing and Can't mass-assign protected attributes: attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to set up a polymorphic association for file uploads. Now pending on the code below, two issues take a very long time. I have searched a lot, but still can't find a resolution

```
#post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content,:tags_attributes, :attachments_attributes
  has_many :tags
  has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
end       

#attachment.rb
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
  attr_accessible :description, :file
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end

# _form.html.erb
<%= form_for @post , :html=>{:multipart => true } do |post_form| %>
  <%= post_form.fields_for :attachments do |attachment_form| %>
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>
      <%= attachment_form.label :description %><br />
      <%= attachment_form.text_area :description %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= attachment_form.label :file %><br />
      <%= attachment_form.file_field :file %>
    </p>
  <% end %> 
  <%= post_form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

It will only show a button on the page, but where is the form part? I think the 
usage of **fields_for** here is correct because I have defined a **tag** model before,
which is almost the same mechanism to access. I use the format of **<%= post_form.fields_for :tags do |tag_form| %>**,but why when it come to polymorphic it show nothing??

As a temporary fix to issue 1, I updated the **fields_for** statement to below, the form now shows on the page, but when I press the **submit** button, the it will prompt the following issue **Can't mass-assign protected attributes: attachment**

```
<%= post_form.fields_for @post.attachments.build do |attachment_form| %>
```

Anyone who can help me to resolve these two issues?

Answer (score 0):

at last, I just add **<% @post.attachments.build %>** at the beginning of file _form.html.erb,
then these two issues are resolved.